# KOMA-Script installed but class not found

Tags: koma-script, texlive

I have a basic scheme of TeX Live installed. I installed the KOMA-Script package via tlmgr but when I try to compile my document, I get the ! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not found. I also tried with another class (scrbook). I used a MWE example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

I paste below the output when compiling from terminal:

```
(base) ignacio@ThinkPadE14g3:~$ tlmgr install koma-script
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] install: footmisc [533k]
[2/2, 00:01/00:14] install: koma-script [7176k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: command log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
(base) ignacio@ThinkPadE14g3:~$ cd Downloads/
(base) ignacio@ThinkPadE14g3:~/Downloads$ pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>

! LaTeX Error: File `scrartcl.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does file `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls` exist? Is there another TeX Live (maybe from your Linux distribution) installed? What are the results of `which pdflatex` and `which tlmgr`? The current koma-script package of TeX Live definitely contains `scrarticl.cls`.

Comment: if you use article, from where it is taken?

Comment: @cabohah thanks for your comment. `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls` does exist. which pdflatex: `usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex` and which tlmgr: `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I compiled with article and it returned `usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`

Comment: This is really strange. Try `sudo texhash`.

Comment: @cabohah that did the trick. Any idea what it was? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems, that for some unknown reason, the ls-R update did not run after package installation. This should not happen and I do not know, why it happened.

Comment: @cabohah well your suggestion helped to update it and make it work so if you want to add it as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you told in an command the class file `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls` does not exist and this is also the tree used by your TeX Live distribution. So not finding `scrartcl.cls` usually happens, because the ls-R database has not been updated after installation of package `koma-script`. I do not know, why this happens. But manually updating it should help. To do so, you should either use `texhash` or `sudo texhash` (`sudo` is only needed, of your user has not permission to write to directory `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/`).

Alternatively you could try `tlmgr install --reinstall koma-script` (use `sudo` if needed) to re-install `koma-script` and `kpsewhich scrartcl.cls` to see whether the ls-R database has been updated by the re-installation.

Comment: Using `sudo texhash` resolved the problem. Thanks